# What's wrong with .flv file?

Tags: vlc-media-player, flv

I have .flv file which has a pretty long runtime.
But VLC player indicates runtime as 48 min. (in reality it's more than 2 hours)

The questions: What is the maximum runtime for .flv file?

What causes this error? Why can't it display the actual runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FLV is a container format](http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf) and has no real limit on runtime.
The problem in your case is most likely that the index or the metadata (where duration, codec info, resolution, keyframes etc are stored) has been corrupted.

There are programs that can rebuild or repair the index for you.